# Put all parameters from a session into variables

Tags: php, arrays, session, variables, parameters

I have the following code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["spgrund"])) {
    $spgrund = $_SESSION["spgrund"];
}else{
    $spgrund = '';
}
```

This code is repeated about 20 times for each session variable. How can I make a loop out of it?

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

I think that should work. But I get `undefined variable` error messages. Can't I use such a loop?

Comment: what's the error message exactly ? which line?

Comment: The line comes from my script below. Therein I have `echo` and some `if ($spgrund == "1")`.

Answer (score 3):

What you actually try to achieve is already available in PHP, the [`extract`*­Docs*](http://php.net/extract) function:

```
extract($_SESSION);
```

From it's documentation:

> Import variables from an array into the current symbol table.
>
> Checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name. It also checks for collisions with existing variables in the symbol table.

You would still need look for undefined variables however. Probably you should define them first?

Comment: If I first use `$spgrund='';` and then `extract` it takes the first defined empty value...

Comment: That is because `spgrund` is not a key of `$_SESSION`. Use `var_dump($_SESSION)` to look what's inside that variable. This probably helps you.

Comment: It is in the session (`print_r ($_SESSION);`). Also used `var_dump` and it prints `&string(4) "test"`. But echo is empty ...

Comment: If I comment out `$spgrund='';` than it works, but I get undefined variable errors. Now more about my code: I have a form which sends to form_do.php. Therein all POST Parameters are set into SESSION variables and I make a redirect to form.php, which was calling form_do.php. I think I have to leave the old way because I spent to much time on improving this ...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
    $$key = $value;
}
```

you missed the `$` for value

Comment: Thanks! I had a typo here, but already corrected in my script. The problem is that some variables are not set, but there are some `if` which seems to need it. Is there a way to optimize the code (20 times the same code) within a foreach?